# Lexical Analyzer Prolog

Tags: prolog, lexical-analysis

I must make a lexical analyzer in Prolog and C++. My for lexical analyzer in C++ is working, but i have some problems with my prolog code. I can't make it to recognize the keywords

This is my prolog code for it without including the keywords which works\

```
predicates

string_processing
det_lexical_atom_type(char)
is_identif(char)
is_op(char)
is_delim(char)
is_const(char)
p1(string)

clauses

string_processing:-write("Write the expression"),nl,readln(S),p1(S).
p1(S):-frontchar(S,C,R),det_lexical_atom_type(C),p1(R).
p1("#"):-!.

det_lexical_atom_type(C):-is_identif(C),write("\n Is identif",C).
det_lexical_atom_type(C):-is_op(C),write("\n is op",C).
det_lexical_atom_type(C):-is_delim(C),write("\n is delim",C).
det_lexical_atom_type(C):-is_const(C),write("\n is const",C).

det_lexical_atom_type(C):-write("\n Unknown lexical atom").

is_identif(C):-C='A'.
is_op(C):-C='+';C='*'.
is_delim(C):-C='(';C=')'.
is_const(C):-C='0';C='1'.
```

And this is my prolog code modified to recognize keywords, but it doesn't work .The program stops reading the expression I give right after the first letter and it doesn't continue to recognize the rest of expression. For example is i type T=3+a, it only reads the T and then it stops

```
predicates

string_processing
is_identif(char)
is_op(char)
is_delim(char)
is_const(char)
is_keyword(string)
p2(string)
determine_lexical_atom_type(char)
determine_keyword(string)

clauses

 is_identif(C):-C='A';C='B';C='C';C='D'.
 is_op(C):-C='+';C='-';C='/';C='*';C='='.
 is_delim(C):-C=';';C=',';C='(';C=')'.
 is_const(C):-C='0';C='1';C='2';C='3';C='4';C='5';C='6';C='7';C='8';C='9'.
 is_keyword(T):-T="if";T="while";T="do";T="switch";T="for";
    T="break";T="until";T="then".
 determine_keyword(T):-is_keyword(T),write("\nIs keyword: ",T).
 determine_lexical_atom_type(C):-is_identif(C),write("\nIs identif:",C).
 determine_lexical_atom_type(C):-is_op(C),write("\nIs operator: ",C).
 determine_lexical_atom_type(C):-is_delim(C),write("\nIs delimiter: ",C).
 determine_lexical_atom_type(C):-is_const(C),write("\n Is constant ",C).
 determine_lexical_atom_type(C):-write("\n Unknown lexical atom").
 p2(S):-  fronttoken(S,T,R),write("\nT=",T),determine_keyword(T),frontchar(R,C,R1),determine_lexical_atom_type(C),p2(R1).   
 p2("#"):-!.
 string_processing:-write("Write expression"),nl,readln(S),p2(S),nl.
```

Comment: You may want to add a specific error or unknown behavior. This way users can help you fix it.

Comment: Using TurboProlog has greatly limited the number of people who can assist you. If you were using something modern like SWI, you would probably get more help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple:

Just move `determine_keyword/1` before `fronttoken/3`, code fragment is below. Keyword recognition should work after doing that.

```
p2(S):-    
  determine_keyword(T), //output var
  fronttoken(S,T,R),
  write("\nT=",T),
  frontchar(R,C,R1),
  determine_lexical_atom_type(C), 
  fail.

p2(_).
```

`determine_keyword/1` generates list of all the keywords on backtracking